# Omnidirectional Image (sphere model) check epipolar constraint

Tags: computer-vision

I'm struggling with the verification of the essential matrix based on the sphere model for omnidirectional images in a RANSAC scheme. [See here](http://snag.gy/6kirO.jpg) for a visualization of the sphere model.

To eliminate outliers, the essential/fundamental matrix is calculated in a RANSAC scheme for only 8 points per iteration. To find the most correct essential matrix and reject outliers the epipolar constraint has to be checked.

The original code checks the epipolar constraint for the fundamental matrix in the pinhole case, where the w-component of the pixel is 1.

As I have to use the sphere model I do not calculate the fundamental but the essential matrix directly with the projected image points from the cam to the unit sphere. This part is working.
But when I  try to check the epipolar constraint for the essential matrix based on the unit vectors to the sphere, the solution is wrong.
In the sphere case the w component is not 1 and I think there is a problem with the check, but I don't find any solution.

Could somebody help me how to adapt the verification of the epipolar constraint for the sphere case?

Here you find the original code with my adaption to use the vectors to the unit sphere:

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    bool bIn = true;

    const cv::KeyPoint &kp1 = mvKeys1[mvMatches12[i].first];
    const cv::KeyPoint &kp2 = mvKeys2[mvMatches12[i].second];

    // original part in the pinhole case
    const float u1 = kp1.pt.x;
    const float v1 = kp1.pt.y;
    const float w1 = 1.0;
    const float u2 = kp2.pt.x;
    const float v2 = kp2.pt.y;
    const float w2 = 1.0;


    // NEW: using the sphere model -> points not anymore on image plane
    cv::Mat X1, X2;

    cam2sphere(kp1.pt.x, kp1.pt.y, X1);
    cam2sphere(kp2.pt.x, kp2.pt.y, X2);

    const float u1 = X1.at<float>(0);
    const float v1 = X1.at<float>(1);
    const float w1 = X1.at<float>(2);
    const float u2 = X2.at<float>(0);
    const float v2 = X2.at<float>(1);
    const float w2 = X2.at<float>(2);



    // Reprojection error in second image
    // l2=F21x1=(a2,b2,c2)

    const float a2 = f11*u1+f12*v1+f13*w1;
    const float b2 = f21*u1+f22*v1+f23*w1;
    const float c2 = f31*u1+f32*v1+f33*w1;

    const float num2 = a2*u2+b2*v2+c2*w2;

    const float squareDist1 = num2*num2/(a2*a2+b2*b2); // ???

    const float chiSquare1 = squareDist1*invSigmaSquare;

    if(chiSquare1>th)
        bIn = false;
    else
        score += thScore - chiSquare1;

    // Reprojection error in first image
    // l1 =x2tF21=(a1,b1,c1)

    const float a1 = f11*u2+f21*v2+f31*w2;
    const float b1 = f12*u2+f22*v2+f32*w2;
    const float c1 = f13*u2+f23*v2+f33*w2;

    const float num1 = a1*u1+b1*v1+c1*w1;

    const float squareDist2 = num1*num1/(a1*a1+b1*b1);

    const float chiSquare2 = squareDist2*invSigmaSquare;


    if(chiSquare2>th)
        bIn = false;
    else
        score += thScore - chiSquare2;

    if(bIn)
        vbMatchesInliers[i]=true;
    else
        vbMatchesInliers[i]=false;
}

return score;
```

I hope my problem is somehow clear. Otherwise I'm glad to give any further explanations.

Thank you very much,
Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer to my own question/problem.

The formulation of the Structure from Motion (SfM) with the error description for spherical images can be found in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6130266&tag=1).

The angular error for the epipolar constraint **m<sub>2</sub><sup>T</sup>*E*m<sub>1</sub>=0** is defined as:

```
    eg = sin-1(m2TEm1)
```

where:

- `e`: epipolar error
- `g`: stands for geodesic

The best approximation for computational efficiency is the *projected distance* error:

```
    ep = |m2TEm1|/(||m2||*||Em1||)
```